# Recover Photos from an iPhone in DFU Mode

Tags: data-recovery, iphone, photos, ios

I have an iPhone 4 that is not jailbroken and crashed when it was updating itself to iOS 5.1. I can go into recovery mode and DFU mode, is there anything I can do to get my photos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RecBoot kicked it out of its funk and corrected the problem.